# Is there any difference between var name = function() {} & function name() {} in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Suppose we are inside a function and not in the global namespace.

```
function someGlobalFunction() {
  var utilFunction1 = function() {
  }

  function utilFunction2 () {
  }

  utilFunction1();
  utilFunction2();

}
```

Are these synonymous? And do these functions completely cease to exist when `someGlobalFunction` returns? Should I prefer one or the other for readability or some other reason?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

They are *mostly* the same.

`utilFunction1` will only be available after it has been declared. `utilFunction2` is hoisted to the top of the function, so can be used before it is defined.

```
function someGlobalFunction() {
  utilFunction1(); // Error: untilFunction1 is undefined :(
  utilFunction2(); // Works

  var utilFunction1 = function() {
  }

  function utilFunction2 () {
  }
}
```

Unless they are trapped in a closure, both will cease to exist when `someGlobalFunction` returns.

I prefer to use the method used to declare `utilFunction2`, but it's up to you.

Declarations of the form `utilFunction2` (which are called Function Declarations) have the benefit of being named (i.e. showing up as `utilFunction2`) in *your-favourite-debugger*<sup>TM</sup>, where as `utilFunction1` (called Function Expressions) would just show up as an *anonymous function*.

---

For completeness, you also have the form;

```
var utilFunction3 = function utilFunction4() {
    // blah
};
```

... which is called a *named* function expression, which has [weird properties](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr) (and [bugs](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) (in older versions of IE)) of its own.

Comment: +1 - Looks like you have everything covered.

Comment: It could also be noted that the first is a FunctionExpression while the latter one is a FunctionDeclaration.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are quite different:

- utilFunction1 has no name, so if it throws an exception, your debugging tool will only tell you that an anonymous function threw up
- utilFunction2 will be available in the scope of the function even before that line is reached (as fletcher noted)
- using the utilFunction2 notation can cause odd behavior in certain circumstances in IE.

Ex:

```
if (true) {
  function utilFunction() {
    return true;
  }
} else {
  function utilFunction() {
    return false;
  }
}

utilFunction(); // returns false in IE, true everywhere else
```

IE takes the function scope issue to the extreme, effectively evaluating functions, even if there is no code path to them!

Comment: Putting a function statement inside an `if` or other non-function-block is not valid in ECMAScript; browser behaviour varies wildly. Avoid!

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations! You've found the situation where Function Hoisting gets involved.

```
var foo = function() { };
```

is quite different than

```
function foo() { };
```

For all the reasons noted elsewhere, plus one.

The second example will be "hoisted" - it will be available anywhere within the current closure (usually the current function). Even before it's declared within said closure.

Something like this would work:

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    function bar() { alert('baz'); }
}
```

Whereas something like this would most definitely not:

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    var bar = function bar() { alert('baz'); };
}
```

You get an error in this second example, because *bar* has not been defined yet. If you swap the two lines in the function *foo*, that example will work.

Douglas Crockford advocates using this second method, because it doesn't contain a hidden behavior like hoisting - your code does exactly what it says it'll do, no tricks involved.